# Passing empty values for MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, isnull

I am trying to pass an empty field in php when searching my database. Currently this is working for me, but since I am new to `mysql` and `php` I would appreciate an alternate or better solution to my project.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $val1 = trim($_POST['tester']);
    if($val1 == NULL){$val1 = "IS NOT NULL";} else {$val1 = "= '$val1'";}
    $val2 = trim($_POST['test']);
    if($val2 == NULL){$val2 = "IS NOT NULL";} else {$val2 = "= '$val2'";}
}
require ('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE Tester $val1 AND Test $val2";
$testerdb = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

Comment: Your query is not secure, use a prepared statement.  If there is nothing wrong, then this is a "code review" question.

Comment: Thanks. I added mysqli_prepare before mysqli_query.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first problem is that you don't check if your $_POST data really exist.

I suggest you to write some kind of helper, for example Request class with following methods

```
public static function post($index)
{
    return isset($_POST[$index]) ? $_POST[$index] : NULL;
}
public static function get($index)
{
    return isset($_GET[$index]) ? $_GET[$index] : NULL;
}
```

For your example, if you search for multiple fields with `AND`, I can suggest you to use array(`$wheres = array();`) which you can add your fields (`$wheres[] = "Tester = $val"`) and then you just need to check whether your array is empty or not. If not, just implode it with `implode` function : (`$where = implode(' AND ', $wheres);`)

So, complete example

```
$wheres = array();
if($tester = Request::post('tester'))
{
    $wheres[] = '`tester` = '.$tester;
}
else
{
   $wheres[] = '`tester` IS NOT NULL';
}

if($test = Request::post('test'))
{
    $wheres[] = '`test` = '.$test;
}
else
{
   $wheres[] = '`test` IS NOT NULL';
}

$where = sizeof($wheres) ? "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $wheres) : "";
require ('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM report $where";
$testerdb = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

Or you can google for Query Builders

P.S. Never forget to escape data that you're going to send to database :)

Comment: Great function there. +1

Comment: `test = Null` is always false, you should use `test is NULL`

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi `if` condition wouldn't allow you to create `test = NULL`. You can always add `else` statement to handle NULL cases.

Comment: @Rulisp so your answer is wrong. you should add else statement

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi fixed